# put different class in hierarchy in one container in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, oop, stl

Some times we have to put different objects in the same hierarchy in one container. I read some article saying there are some tricks and traps. However, I have no big picture about this question. Actually, this happens a lot in the real word.

For example, a parking lot has to contain different types of cars; a zoo has to contain different types of animals; a book store has to contain different types of books.

I remember that one article saying neither of the following is a good design, but I forgot where it is.

```
vector<vehicle> parking_lot;
vector<*vehicle> parking_lot;
```

Can anybody offer some basic rules for this kind of question?

Comment: Remember this question you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237775/how-to-return-different-classes-from-one-function? Many of the issues covered there apply in this case too. And can I suggest a bit less time asking questions, and a bit more designing and writing code, could benefit you enormously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with `vector<vehicle>` is that the object only holds vehicles. The problem with `vector<vehicle*>` is that you need to allocate and, more importantly, free the pointers appropriately.

This might be acceptable, depending on your project, etc...

However, one usually uses some kind of smart-ptr in the vector (`vector<boost::shared_ptr<vehicle>>` or Qt-something, or one of your own) that handles deallocation, but still permits storing different types objects in the same container.

**Update**

Some people have, in other answers/comments, also mentioned `boost::ptr_vector`. That works well as a container-of-ptr's too, and solves the memory deallocation problem by owning all the contained elements. I prefer `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` as I can then store objects all over the place, and move them using in and out of containers w/o issues. It's a more generic usage model that I've found is easier for me and others to grasp, and applies better to a larger set of problems.

Answer (score 6):

I learnt a lot writing my reply to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237775/how-to-return-different-classes-from-one-function) by the same author, so I couldn't resist to do the same here. In short, I've written a benchmark to compare the following approaches to the problem of storing heterogeneous elements in a standard container:

1. Make a class for each type of element and have them all inherit from a common base and store polymorphic base pointers in a `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Base> >`. This is probably the more general and flexible solution:

   ```
   struct Shape {
       ...
   };
   struct Point : public Shape { 
       ...
   };
   struct Circle : public Shape { 
       ...
   };
   std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Shape> > shapes;    
   shapes.push_back(new Point(...));
   shapes.push_back(new Circle(...));
   shapes.front()->draw(); // virtual call
   ```
2. Same as (1) but store the polymorphic pointers in a `boost::ptr_vector<Base>`. This is a bit less general because the elements are owned exclusively by the vector, but it should suffice most of the times. One advantage of `boost::ptr_vector` is that it has the interface of a `std::vector<Base>` (without the *), so its simpler to use.

   ```
    boost::ptr_vector<Shape> shapes;    
    shapes.push_back(new Point(...));
    shapes.push_back(new Circle(...));
    shapes.front().draw(); // virtual call
   ```
3. Use a C union that can contain all possible elements and then use a `std::vector<UnionType>`. This is not very flexible as we need to know all element types in advance (they are hard-coded into the union) and also unions are well known for not interacting nicely with other C++ constructs (for example, the stored types can't have constructors).

   ```
   struct Point { 
       ...
   };
   struct Circle { 
       ...    
   };
   struct Shape {
       enum Type { PointShape, CircleShape };
       Type type;
       union {
           Point p;
           Circle c;
       } data;
   };
   std::vector<Shape> shapes;
   Point p = { 1, 2 };
   shapes.push_back(p);
   if(shapes.front().type == Shape::PointShape)
       draw_point(shapes.front());
   ```
4. Use a `boost::variant` that can contain all possible elements and then use a `std::vector<Variant>`. This is not very flexible like the union but the code to deal with it is much more elegant.

   ```
   struct Point { 
       ...
   };
   struct Circle { 
       ...
   };
   typedef boost::variant<Point, Circle> Shape;
   std::vector<Shape> shapes;
   shapes.push_back(Point(1,2));
   draw_visitor(shapes.front());   // use boost::static_visitor
   ```
5. Use `boost::any` (which can contain anything) and then a `std::vector<boost::any>`. That is very flexible but the interface is a little clumsy and error prone.

   ```
   struct Point { 
       ...
   };
   struct Circle { 
       ...
   };
   typedef boost::any Shape;
   std::vector<Shape> shapes;
   shapes.push_back(Point(1,2));
   if(shapes.front().type() == typeid(Point))    
       draw_point(shapes.front());
   ```

[This is the code](http://codepad.org/1yxYje4I) of the full benchmark program (doesn't run on codepad for some reason). And here are my performance results:

> time with hierarchy and boost::shared_ptr: 0.491 microseconds
>
> time with hierarchy and boost::ptr_vector: 0.249 microseconds
>
> time with union:                           0.043 microseconds
>
> time with boost::variant:                  0.043 microseconds
>
> time with boost::any:                      0.322 microseconds

My conclusions:

- Use `vector<shared_ptr<Base> >` only if you need the flexibility provided by runtime polymorphism **and if** you need shared ownership. Otherwise you'll have significant overhead.
- Use `boost::ptr_vector<Base>` if you need runtime polymorphism but don't care about shared ownership. It will be significantly faster than the `shared_ptr` counterpart and the interface will be more friendly (stored elements not presented like pointers).
- Use `boost::variant<A, B, C>` if you don't need much flexibility (i.e. you have a small set of types which will not grow). It will be lighting fast and the code will be elegant.
- Use `boost::any` if you need total flexibility (you want to store anything).
- Don't use unions. If you really need speed then `boost::variant` is as fast.

Before I finish I want to mention that a vector of [std::unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956611/uniqueptr-major-improvement) will be a good option when it becomes widely available (I think it's already in VS2010)

Comment: I think it's subtly biased: using the heap and `virtual` calls is of course slower than using the stack and normal calls. If you have a hierarchy, you'll want either the `shared_ptr` or the `ptr_vector` approach because they are the only one than don't have you worrying about extending the hierarchy. I am afraid that you're slightly offtopic therefore... but good show down (+1) !

Comment: @Matthieu - Thanks for the feedback! In my answer I say "use `ptr_vector` or `vector<shared_ptr>` if you need the flexibility provided by runtime polymorphism", by which I mean "if you think you might have to extend the hierarchy in the future". So I think we agree on that point. About being offtopic, it's true that the OP mentioned a hierarchy in the title of his question but maybe that's because he didn't know that there were other options like Boost.Variant that he could use.

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, I am not (really) criticizing, it's just that your answer was a bit overwhelming with all that data to digest! But what a good read!

Comment: +1. Good summary! However heap vs. stack might play a role as Matthieu says.

Answer (score 2):

Say `vehicle` is a base class, that has certain properties, then, inheriting from it you have say a `car`, and a `truck`. Then you can just do something like:

```
std::vector<vehicle *> parking_lot;
parking_lot.push_back(new car(x, y));
parking_lot.push_back(new truck(x1, y1));
```

This would be perfectly valid, and in fact very useful sometimes. The only requirement for this type of object handling is sane hierarchy of objects.

Other popular type of objects that can be used like that are e.g. `people` :) you see that in almost every programming book.

EDIT:
Of course that vector can be packed with `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers for ease of memory management. And in fact that's something I would recommend to do by all means possible.

EDIT2:
I removed a not very relevant example, here's a new one:

Say you are to implement some kind of AV scanning functionality, and you have multiple scanning engines. So you implement some kind of engine management class, say `scan_manager` which can call `bool scan(...)` function of those. Then you make an engine interface, say `engine`. It would have a `virtual bool scan(...) = 0;` Then you make a few `engine`s like `my_super_engine` and `my_other_uber_engine`, which both inherit from `engine` and implement `scan(...)`. Then your engine manager would somewhere during initialization fill that `std::vector<engine *>` with instances of `my_super_engine` and `my_other_uber_engine` and use them by calling `bool scan(...)` on them either sequentially, or based on whatever types of scanning you'd like to perform. Obviously what those engines do in `scan(...)` remains unknown, the only interesting bit is that `bool`, so the manager can use them all in the same way without any modification.

Same can be applied to various game units, like `scary_enemies` and those would be `orks`, `drunks` and other unpleasant creatures. They all implement `void attack_good_guys(...)` and your `evil_master` would make many of them and call that method.

This is indeed a common practice, and I would hardly call it bad design for as long as all those types actually are related.

Answer (score 2):

The problems are:

1. You cannot place polymorphic objects into a container since they may differ in size --i.e., you must use a pointer.
2. Because of how containers work a normal pointer / auto pointer is not suitable.

The solution is :

1. Create a class hierarchy, and use at least one virtual function in your base class (if you can't think of any function to virtualize, virtualize the destructor -- which as Neil pointed out is generally a must).
2. Use a [boost::shared_pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) (this will be in the next c++ standard) -- shared_ptr handles being copied around *ad hoc*, and containers may do this.
3. Build a class hierarchy and allocate your objects on the heap --i.e., by using new. The pointer to the base class must be encapsulated by a shared_ptr.
4. place the base class shared_pointer into your container of choice.

---

Once you understand the "whys and hows"  of the points above look at the [boost ptr_containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/headers.html) -- thanks to Manual for the tip.

Comment: In fact, the base destructor MUST be virtual, whether you have any other virtual functions or not. Otherwise, this design leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Provided any RAII is going on in the class :D

Comment: No. shared_pointer must at some point call delete on its managed pointer. Calling delete on a base pointer that actually points to derived type is undefined behaviour if there is no virtual destructor. What is "going on in the class" is neither here nor there.

Comment: @Hassan - A `boost::ptr_vector` is probably a better choice than a `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr> >`

Comment: Hmm interesting, shame there isn't a boost::ptr_set / ptr_map.

Comment: @Hassan - yes there are, google for boost ptr_container library

Comment: @Munual thanks mate, those will really come in handy :D. Shame that my question is voted at the end, no one will look at that information.

Comment: @Manuel: Fine point: Not if you also want the objects to be somewhere else, and not solely owned by the container. But I think the OP would probably benefit from ptr_vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this Stroustrup's answer to the question [Why can't I assign a vector< Apple*> to a vector< Fruit*>?](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html).